# reusable removeAlert function

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to make this html table re-usable? I use the same table in 2 places and am using props dependant on its use. There is 1 thing I can't work out. Each instance of the table uses an onclickhandler with a parameter, 1 to delete the user (user.id) and the other to add the user (user), so each onClick takes different arguments.

example of 1 of the onClickHandler's

```
    const onClickHandler = (user) => {
        setAddedAlert(true);
        removeAlert()
        setFavourites([...favourites, user]);
    };
```

example of the table being used in a component and props passed

```
            {usersData &&
                <Table
                    data={usersData}
                    onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
                    buttonText={"Add"}
                />
            }
        </div>
```

example of table

```
const Table = ({ data, onClickHandler, buttonText }) => (
    <Container>
        <StyledTable>
            <THead>
                <TR>
                    <TH>ID</TH>
                    <TH>NAME</TH>
                    <TH>PHONE</TH>
                </TR>
            </THead>
            <TBody>
                {data?.map((user) => (
                    <TR key={user.id} >
                        <TD>{user.id}</TD>
                        <TD>{user.name}</TD>
                        <TD>{user.phone}</TD>
                        <TD>
                            <Button
                                onClick={() => onClickHandler(user)}
                            >
                                {buttonText}
                            </Button>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                ))}
            </TBody>
        </StyledTable>
    </Container>
)

export default Table;
```

Comment: The answer to your question of "Is it possible to make this html table re-usable?" is yes.  Rework your post so that you're asking for something less ambiguous.

Comment: This is the question: Each instance of the table uses an onclickhandler with a parameter, 1 to delete the user (user.id) and the other to add the user (user), so each onClick takes different arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate function for add and remove would do the job.

```
function App() {
    const data = [
        { id: 1, name: "Jay", phone: "1111111111" },
        { id: 2, name: "Mike", phone: "2222222222" },
        { id: 3, name: "Bob", phone: "3333333333" },
    ];

    const [userData] = useState(data);
    const [faveUsers, setFaveUsers] = useState([]);

    const onClickHandleAdd = (user) => {
        const newFaveUsers = [...faveUsers, user];
        setFaveUsers(newFaveUsers);
    };
    const onClickHandleRemove = (user) => {
        const newFaveUsers = faveUsers.filter((u) => u.id !== user.id);
        setFaveUsers(newFaveUsers);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Table
                data={userData}
                onClickHandler={onClickHandleAdd}
                buttonText="Add"
            />
            <Table
                data={faveUsers}
                onClickHandler={onClickHandleRemove}
                buttonText="Remove"
            />
        </>
    );
}
```